# a float variable mysteriously taken as a string

Tags: python, shell

this is the main of my code

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
    import time
    import sys
    import numpy
    import random
    from random import randint  
    from configurable_trace_gen import ssatrace, random_trace

    def main():
        K = random.randint(150, 200)
        if (len(sys.argv) >= 3):
            probability = [float(x) for x in sys.argv[1:3]]
            ratio=sys.argv[-1]
            trace = random_trace(K, probability, ratio)
            run=ssatrace(trace)
            print( K, probability, ratio)
            print(run)
        else:
            print('Params Error')
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

and  I have this shell script to execute the **main.py** (the code above) several times while changing the arguments in the input: **$short** **$long** **$ratio**

```
#!/bin/bash
step=0.05
short=0
long=1
for firstloop in {1..20}; do
    ratio=0
    for secondloop in {1..20} ; do
        echo $short $long $ratio >> file.txt
        time python3 main.py "$short" "$long" "$ratio">> output.txt
        ratio=$(echo "scale=10; $ratio + $step" | bc)
    done
    short=$(echo "scale=10; $short + $step" | bc)
    long=$(echo "scale=10; $long - $step" | bc)
done
```

when Executing, for some reason the variable **ratio** is considered to be a string which I don't understand why! **ratio** is supposed to take the last value of the 3 arguments in the command line, while **probability** is alist that is supposed to contain **$short** and **$long**.

this is a snip of the output I get:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

real    0m0.511s
user    0m0.416s
sys 0m0.076s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 20, in main
    trace = random_trace(K, probability, ratio)
  File "/Users/ouafaelachhab/Desktop/SemanticLocality/src/configurable_trace_gen.py", line 34, in random_trace
    ratioList=[ratio, 1-ratio]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Just like you needed to explicitly convert the probabilities to `float`s, you need to do the same for `ratio`: `ratio = int(sys.argv[-1])`.

Comment: Every item in `sys.argv` will be a `str`

Comment: If you look at the operating-system level interface, arguments are passed to and between programs as an array of pointers to C strings. There's no possible way for them to ever be anything *except* a string.

Comment: ...moreover, shell variables are strings too, whether or not those strings are used to represent numbers! `ratio=$(echo "scale=10; $ratio + $step" | bc)` is reading the output of the `bc` command... *into a nul-terminated C string*.

Comment: I modified it to `ratio = float(sys.argv[-1])` and now it is working!